# Proving time complexity for recursive function

Tags: java, algorithm, time, binary-tree, big-o

How would I prove that the time complexity of this algorithm that finds the depth of a binary tree is O(N) where N is the number of nodes? I understand the reasoning why this is true, since the algorithm checks each node once, but I'm not sure how I would mathematically prove this. Thanks!

```
private static int depth(TreeNode node){
    if(node == null){
        return 0;
    }

    int leftDepth = depth(node.left);
    int rightDepth = depth(node.right);

    return 1 + Math.max(leftDepth, rightDepth);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Let's assume that we visited any of the vertices 2 times. This means that there is an edge from the current vertex to the vertex that we have already visited, that is, we have found a cycle in the tree-a contradiction. So, we visit each vertex only once, hence the complexity of the algorithm is O (n).

Answer (score 0):

You are traversing both branches of every node, and there is only one path to each node, so you will visit each node exactly once, which itself is O(n).

The operation of traversing from one node to another is constant time.

Overall, you have O(n) operations each costing O(1), so your algorithm is O(n).

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I understand that the algorithm visits each node once, but is there a way to mathematically prove the time complexity of the algorithm?

Comment: This is the proof: You visit each node once and the operation of traversing from one node to another is constant time. Answer edited to spell it out.

Comment: Also, would it be correct to say that it runs in O(log H) where H is the depth of the tree?

Comment: No, it would not be correct, because to find the maximum depth **all nodes must be visited**. It's O(n). It doesn't matter how balanced or unbalanced the tree is. Think of it this way: there is no way to know how deep a rabbit hole goes unless you go down the rabbit hole, and here the rabbit hole is the longest unbroken chain of descending nodes.

Comment: Whoops I made a mistake, I meant to ask if O(2^H) is correct. In the worst case where the tree is complete, would that be correct since log N = H?

Comment: @DexMax No. It’s O(n), as per explanation.